# How to remove error in the following code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

```
n=int(raw_input())
w=set(map(int,raw_input().split()))
N=int(raw_input())
L=list()
for i in range(N):
    w=raw_input()
    L.append(w)
for i in range(N):
    x=[]
    x=L[i].split()
    #print x[0]
    if (x[0]=='pop'):
        w.pop()

    elif (x[0]=='remove'):
        w.remove(int(x[1]))
    elif (x[0]=='discard'):
        w.discard(int(x[1]))
    else:
        continue
print sum(w)
```

The error comes out to be:-
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'** in **line 13** i.e. w.pop()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the code:

```
for i in range(N):
    w=raw_input()
    L.append(w)
```

which rebinds the name "w" to a string, with this:

```
for i in range(N):
    z=raw_input()
    L.append(z)
```

which leaves the name "w" bound to a set.